# How to automatically set a value in drop-down list based on a value from another drop-down list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a googlesheet with Columns A - P.  Column B (GROUP) is a dropdown list and Column N (EXECUTION STATUS) is a drop-down list. I am trying to automatically set a particular value in a cell for GROUP  based on the value that I selected in the EXECUTION STATUS dropdown list.

**For Example:**
GROUP has the following values in the drop-down list:

DEVELOPER
QA
LEVEL 1 SUPPORT
LEVEL 2 SUPPORT

EXECUTION STATUS has the following values in the drop-down list:

PASSED
FAILED
NOT EXECUTED
BLOCKED

Here is what I want to happen:
If I select **FAILED** as the EXECUTION STATUS, I want the GROUP to automatically change to **DEVELOPER**.

Here is my function:

```html
function changeGroup(event)
{
  var ColN = 14;  // Column Number of "N"
  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColN) 
  {
    // An edit has occurred in Column N
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var Group = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColN-12);
    switch (state) 
    {
      case "FAILED":
        // Select DEVELOPER from dropdown list
        Group.setValue("Developer");
        break
      
    }
  }
}
```

I think my problem is the **Group.setValue("Developer")** line. SetValue is setting a text value.  I am trying to set a value  from the drop-down list.  I'm not sure.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data validation rules distinguishes the uppercase and lowercase letters. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So if your values of data validation rules are `DEVELOPER` of the uppercase letter, please use it as follows.

```
Group.setValue("DEVELOPER");
```

#### Note:

- In your script, I think that the OnEdit event trigger of the simple trigger can be used. But from your script, it seems that you are using the installable event trigger. So please confirm whether the function of `changeGroup` is installed as the installable OnEdit event trigger, again.
- By the way, if you want to run the script for the specific sheet, please modify `if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColN)` as follows.

  ```
    if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColN && changedRange.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Sheet1")
  ```

#### References:

- [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

### Added:

In your case, the simple trigger can be also used. So how about testing the following script? When you use this script, please copy and paste the following script. Then, please change the dropdown list at the column "N".

```
function onEdit(event)  // <--- Modified
{
  var ColN = 14;  // Column Number of "N"
  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColN) 
  {
    // An edit has occurred in Column N
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var Group = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColN-12);
    switch (state) 
    {
      case "FAILED":
        // Select DEVELOPER from dropdown list
        Group.setValue("DEVELOPER");
        break
      
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: @April Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I thought that from your script, you are using the installable OnEdit event trigger. About this, is my understanding correct? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Comment: your suggestion worked.  I changed the first line from                           
 function changeGroup(event) to function onEdit(event)

Comment: @April In your case, the simple trigger can be also used as mentioned above. So I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The modified script worked.